# How to connect toad, SQL developer and SSMS using ODBC?

Tags: sql, oracle, cmd, odbc, ssms

I need to connect oracle and SQL server databases using ODBC by the following application.

1. Toad
2. SQL Developer
3. SSMS
4. CMD

Is there a way to connect these applications thru ODBC. If yes could you please help me with this.

I have already created DSN for both oracle and SQL, but other steps are unknown since I don't if I can connect these applications to a database using ODBC

Comment: What do you mean by `CMD`?

Comment: Toad uses native Oracle OCI. SQL Developer is Java based and thus uses JDBC - so no ODBC for either.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding and mixing things.

- Toad is a product of Quest Software, an IDE ( Integrated Development Environment ) based on OCI. The best known version is the one which is designed to interact with Oracle databases..
- SQL Developer is also an IDE, though less powerful than Toad, but
  free. It is based on Java and it can connect to Oracle, MySQL, Postgres .
- SSMS is SQL Server Management Studio , which is the client IDE to interact with Microsoft SQL Server.
- CMD is also know as the command prompt for windows which it does't make any sense in this context.

If you want to connect Oracle to SQL Server you have two options:

- Oracle HS or Heterogeneus Services
- SQL Server Linked Server